# How do I enable kerning in WPF?

Tags: wpf, typography, kerning

I am trying to enable kerning in my WPF TextBlock as in

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="Garamond" FontSize="120" Typography.Kerning="True">Table</TextBlock>
<TextBlock FontFamily="Garamond" FontSize="120" Typography.Kerning="False">Table</TextBlock>
```

However, setting Kerning to True or False does not seem to make any difference.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hey, this might shed some light for you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7c4a9e39-d160-451d-9cc8-bb75790d4a2d

Answer (score 1):

I think that property only means anything in the context of a flowdocument.  So you'd need to encapsulate your code in a flowdocument.  Even then, I'm not sure it would work because according to the documentation, you can't set that property in xaml.

[See this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.typography.aspx)

Unless I'm looking at the wrong property, in which case ignore this.

Answer (score 0):

[Typography.Kerning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.typography.kerning.aspx) defaults to true. You've not changed anything.

Comment: Indeed, I slightly changed my question.